# How to return multiple list components using react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand that you can't return multiple elements.
But this limitation is causing me to not be able to solve this problem without help.

I am working with an HTML design from another that uses a 1 depth list to represent a 3 depth list.  As a last resort I can change this.

An example of the HTML I am converting to React. The number of Devices, cards and remotes could all be different on every GET request.

```
 <ul class='deviceList'>
   <li>Device A`</li>
   <li>Cards Connected in Device A</li>
   <li>Card 1</li>
   <li>Card 2</li>
   <li>Remotes Connected to Device A</li>
   <li>Remote 1</li>
   <li>Device B</li>
   <li>Cards Connected to Device B</li>
   <li>Card 1</li>
   <!-- ... could go on for more ...-->
 </ul>
```

This is how I setup the React code that actually contains the `<ul>`:

```
var DeviceList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var deviceList = this.props.devices.map(function (device) {
      return [
        <DeviceTitle title='{device.name}' />,
        <ComponentTitle title='Cards' />,
        <Cards cards={device.cards} />,
        <ComponentTitle title='Remotes' />,
        <Remotes remotes={device.remotes} />
      ];
    });

    return (
      <ul className='deviceList'>
        {deviceList}
      </ul>
    );    
  }
});
```

So the problem is the Card and Remote components need to return multiple list components. I tried having it return an array of list components but this did not work.

Here is what I have .. this is the part that fails.

```
var cards = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var cards = this.props.cards.map(function (card) {
       return (
         <li>{card.name}</li>
       );
    });

    // illegal
    return {{cards});
  }
});

// Remote is a little different but same problem
```

Also.. to try to make this simpler I only showed a 3 depth list but really it is 4 depths.  Each card and remote could have other components attached to them.

So as other questions here have shown. I can't do it this way. So what should I do?

Comment: You could try to have only this code in the render function - ` return this.props.cards.map(function (card) { return (<li>{card.name}</li>) });` It should work.

Comment: I did find a way to do this without resorting to a nested list. I still think that a nested list is the correct way to do it but I did post my answer on the alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `return {{cards}};` isn't valid JavaScript. You only use curly braces like that in JSX. (Also you were missing a closing parenthesis on line 6.)  `cards` is just a regular JavaScript variable, so your function should return it just like any other variable:

```
var cards = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var cards = this.props.cards.map(function (card) {
       return (
         <li>{card.name}</li>
       );
    });

    return <ul>{cards}</ul>;
});
```

Of course, returning a `<ul>` instead of an array of `<li>`s isn't exactly what you wanted, but as a matter of generating sensible markup, it makes sense for `Cards` and `Remotes` to be child lists instead of dumping them all into a single list.

Comment: Why is more sensible markup the "last resort"? Isn't it better to fix things now, which will be a win for you in terms of maintainability and a win for users in terms of usability, than to bend over backwards to try to accommodate bad markup?

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with that philosophy, but to each their own. I think the best solution, then, is to just output the items as above (with a parent `<ul>`) and then use CSS to make them appear as though it's the same list. It should be easy. Any other solution is going to either cost you a lot of time and hassle now or at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var cards = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
   var cards = this.props.cards.map(function (card) {
     return (
       <li>{card.name}</li>
     );
   };
   return (<ul>{cards}</ul>);
 }
});
```

Comment: While this is what I wanted to avoid. It does seem like the only way.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to solve this. Not saying it is the best but it is the only method I could figure out.

You can use a plain javascript function. Since they have no constraint on what you can return. Then I just used concat on the array that is created for the actual list to add these elements.

```
function Card(device) {
    return device.cards.map(function(card) {
       return (<li>{card.name}</li>);
    });
}
```

Comment: I did end up just wrapping it in `<ul>` but this did work.